# Hero harmonica, 16 holes double reed, what type is it?

Tags: harmonica

I have this harmonica, 16 holes double reed, a Hero brand. I am not sure what type of harmonica this is, tremolo or chromatic or whatever else. So, anyone having the same harmonica or knows about this specific harmonica, please answer. Also, if possible, post a note or external link on learning to play it.

[image: Hero Harmonica 16 holes, double reed.]

Comment: Button at high end = chromatic. No button = diatonic.

Comment: Two rows of holes makes me think tremolo. Can we get a recording of you playing it?